# How can I stretch grid columns inside a ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've created this `ListBox` where I've set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` so it covers the full width of the application.

In the ListBox I've created a Grid with 4 Columns:

```
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The layout I want is the first column to take up as much space as it can, and the three other just take what they need.

In the columns i have `Textboxes` and `Image` (one, in the 2nd column).

What happens here is that everything is stacked left to right:

```
| Long_Text Image Text Text                 |
```

instead of

```
| Long_Text                 Image Text Text |
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ListBox ItemContainerStyle

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a GridView instead?

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[MSDN: GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't see how it will utilize the full width, and if it does... what property makes it do that... maybe I can apply it to ListBox?

Comment: My apologies, it seems that the gridview doesn't support star width as I recalled. Only DataGrid does that. To achieve star width on a gridview column, a converter could be used http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83bd7ab9-3407-461f-a0bc-69e04870075c/star-size-of-a-listview-column?forum=wpf